# Search for Hostname in DJigger doesnt find anything

Tags: java, thread-dump, apm, djigger

I set up the DJigger Collector and configured some hosts in the csv file, i.e.

```
ITEST01A;12001;djigger;D:/djigger/password.conf;10000;env;QA;app;myApp;node;1
```

Connecting to the collector with the DJigger client and searching for 'host' or 'hostname' (tried values 'ITEST01A' and 'itest01a') didn't produce any result. How am I supposed to lookup for the collected data for a specific host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are searching data that isn't referenced via the "host" nor "hostname" **keys**.

When using the CSV file format for configuring JMX connections in collector mode, you need to keep in mind that there are two types of information on each line (for each connection definition) :

- the first 5 **properties** (hostname, port number, jmx user, jmx password and sampling rate) are technical information which allow the collector to connect to the JVM you wish to monitor. These properties are mendatory (although user and password can be left empty).
- the columns that come after that are a succession of key-value pairs. It is **metadata** that will allow you to differenciate, find and load the stacktrace data from different JVMs and logical user-defined JVM groups.

The mendatory technical properties are not used as medata per default.

Therefore, if you wish to identify a JVM based on the hostname of the machine it is running on, I would suggest using the following config line (see the values I added in the last two columns) :

```
ITEST01A;12001;djigger;D:/djigger/password.conf;10000;env;QA;app;myApp;node;1;hostname;ITEST01A
```